# IIS and Apache, ip locked

Tags: apache, iis-7.5

i have a server with two public IP, the first is used by IIS, the second IP is configured in Apche in Listen directive. But when i run Apache service i receive the error:

```
make_sock: could not bind to address <ip address>:80
```

All web sites in IIS are binding on first IP.

P.S. Sorry for my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS lock all ip on port 80 (0.0.0.0:80).

I found this: [Stop http.sys from listening on port 80 in Windows](http://www.mikeplate.com/2011/11/06/stop-http-sys-from-listening-on-port-80-in-windows/)

you can use:

```
netsh http add iplisten ipaddress=127.0.0.1
```

This 'release' all ip (not 127.0.0.1) and Apache works!